# usort, not sorting correctly on Hosted Web

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I am trying to sort images by its created time, and it looks well on local server. However, when I try the same on my hosted web, heroku, it seems not to work. Is there something I am missing or should I do another way to sort it for hosted website?

**usort with a function**

```
usort($images, function($a, $b) {
    return filemtime($a) > filemtime($b);
});
```

[Hosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX6eO.png)

[Local Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEsJX.png)

Comment: Because the files were uploaded in a different order than on your local machine.

Comment: @Sammitch oh wait so the created time of the files on the hosted are the same?

Comment: That's not the created time, mtime is modified time.  When you upload a file, depending on how you uploaded it, it may not keep the same timestamps.  Certain methods can be used to do so, like `scp -p`

Comment: @Devon well, no matter what, it only sorts alphabetically

Comment: Have they been uploaded alphabetically? Just for the sake of eliminating this probability. Modify one of those files, maybe the last one in the "z"s if there are any and try again (Live on your server). If it gets on top of everything, you will have your answer. If not, then we can look up for something else..

Comment: @Lou Yes they have, and I can see how they are sorted in the folder and yes its uploaded alphabetically

Comment: I tried to remove image by image and upload it again one by one, but they were sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @Lou Well, I just checked its modified time using filemtime but it displays the same number. No way.

Comment: Can you state your function that uses to get the files?

Comment: @awran5                                                                                       
$images = glob($directory . "/*.{jpg,PNG,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Try this, tested and seemed to work fine:

```
// compare by time
function cbt($a, $b) {
    if ( filemtime($a) == filemtime($b) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (filemtime($a) < filemtime($b) ) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Images array, (case sensitive)
$imgArray = glob($directory . "/*.{jpg,PNG,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);

// sort by date modified
usort($imgArray, "cbt");
// $imgArray = array_reverse($imgArray); // reverse order if you want
```

Tested on PHP v5.6.25, v7.2.3

Comment: I think the problem is that the files have the same modified time, and I tried this one as well

Comment: I think its possible, while testing, I got some images returns the exact same value. Check the update maybe it will help.

Comment: Well, I tried this on it. It is the same as before. My local server fine, but on the hosting, no.